# "Cannot modify header information" error in my PHP/WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I edited the `header.php` and `functions.php` files in my WordPress site to add Google Analytics tracking code. Now, when I try to login to my admin area, the following warning appears and I am unable to login to my WordPress account:

> Warning:
>
> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at
>   /home/wwwwww/public_html/wp-content/themes/poker-complex/functions.php:11)
>   in /home/wwwwww/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Remove all white space (spaces and carriage returns) before any opening `<?php` or `<?` tags and after all closing `?>` tags in all PHP files you've modified.

Answer (score 2):

Also remove the UTF BOM ([Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)). AFAIK PHP doesn't support UTF BOM on its files, and to send utf-8 code the best way is adding headers like this one:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
?>
```

and also metadata

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```